# how to prevent access by status

Tags: codeigniter

i have code like this

my model:

```html
function get_status()
 {
  $nik=$this->session->userdata('nik');
  $this->db->select('*');
  $this->db->where('nik',$nik);
  $this->db->from('t_trx_activity');
  $query= $this->db->get();
  return $query->result();

 }
```

my controller:

```html
public function input()
 {
  $status  = $this->activity->get_status();
  if ($status->status ==1) {
   redirect ('activity');
  } else {
  $data = array(
    'title'     => 'Activity',
    'breadcrumb'=> 'Input Activity'
  );
  

  $this->load->view ( 'default', $data );
  }

 }
```

my problem when status=1 site can access,i hope i can't access site and redirect other site.
how to prevent acccess when status=1?

Comment: ```$query->result();``` produce standard class object. You need to check the output of ```get_status()``` method. Just do ```var_dump``` or ```print_r``` on ```$status```.

Comment: the result status=0,how to prevent if status=1

Answer (score 0):

What value your storing in status field in 't_trx_activity' table?

By default if your storing it is as '1' then condition is always true and it will be redirected.

Comment: the value status in table is 0,1,2,3,4, if status=1 can't acess or redirect other site,else can access.